# How to cite a paper with or without brackets?

Tags: citing

How to cite a paper with brackets over the years in the body of an article?
Thanks for any help！

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}
\geometry{top=1.4in,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
    \citealp{Gil}
    (\citealp{Gil})
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{pa}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try `\citet{jon90}`?

Comment: Check the journal you want to publish in, or book series. If you are self publishing, do whichever you like; they both like fine to me.

Comment: Yes, I just find it helps.

Comment: @ChYh Can you go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do? Up to now you did not accept a single answer.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I understood your questions correctly, but if you want parenthesis around the year, you can use `\citet{}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}
\geometry{top=1.4in,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
    \citealp{bet06}

    (\citealp{bet06})

    \citet{bet06}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]